# Improve repetitive code - R tables

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, refactoring

```
table1 <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9,12),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
table2 <- matrix(c(31,72,55,94,24,21,6,22,9,12),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
table3 <- matrix(c(55,7,22,33,21,111,64,221,92,10),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

Three tables with the same structure.

I'd like to do the same data manipulation to all of the tables above.

```
rownames(table1) <- c("x", "y", "z", "v", "p")
table1 <- table1[!rownames(table1) %in% c("z", "p"), ]
```

Above I've renamed the rows and then removed them depending on the string for table1.

Rather then repeating this code above for all three tables, how could I do this manipulation to all the tables at once?

Thanks

Comment: you can make a function if you know!

Comment: Btw what's the point of naming those rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier. Use `lapply` so you don´t have to write the function three times.

```
table1 <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9,12),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
table2 <- matrix(c(31,72,55,94,24,21,6,22,9,12),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
table3 <- matrix(c(55,7,22,33,21,111,64,221,92,10),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

#function 
tablemodification<-function(yourtable){
  rownames(yourtable) <- c("x", "y", "z", "v", "p")
  yourtable <- yourtable[!rownames(yourtable) %in% c("z", "p"), ]
}

lapply(list(table1, table2, table3), tablemodification)
```

Answer (score 0):

With function for re-usability!

```
   table1 <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9,12),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
table2 <- matrix(c(31,72,55,94,24,21,6,22,9,12),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
table3 <- matrix(c(55,7,22,33,21,111,64,221,92,10),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

do_this <- function(table) {
  rownames(table) <- c("x", "y", "z", "v", "p")
  return(table[!rownames(table) %in% c("z", "p"), ])
}

table1 <- do_this(table1)
table2 <- do_this(table2)
table3 <- do_this(table3)
    > 
    > table3
      [,1] [,2]
    x   55    7
    y   22   33
    v   64  221
    >
```